# Spring Security + Container Managed Security

Tags: spring-security, cxf, csrf

I have a web application which exposes CXF JAX WS SOAP Services and also an OData REST Service.

As i understand from the spring documentations, in order to authenticate the JAX WS requests we need to create a Interceptor and write our own code to call the spring security Authentication Manager to authenticate the request. This i am able to achieve in my application. But in order to use spring security with JAX WS i have to disable the csrf for the endpoint urls.

Hence i dont want to use spring security for authentication and instead wants to use the container managed security where i can do the check in web.xml itself.

But there are certain roles i want to check at method levels and i find spring security pretty helpful at method level security.

So my question is whether i can use container manage authentication and for authorizations spring security ? Do you see any security issues here ?

and in case i want to enable the csrf for the jax WS endpoints then how can we pass the csrf token for a service call?

Regards,
Soumya Ranjan